# Pass polymer form data to rest api

Tags: forms, rest, polymer

I'm looking for some way to pass data from a Polymer form fields to REST API,
actually, I'm using core-ajax to do it but I think is a bit heavy method to do it.

Are any standard way to do it?

This is my code:

```
<template>
<section>
    <file-input class="blue" id="file" extensions='[ "xls" ]' maxFiles="1">{{ FileInputLabel }}</file-input>
</section>
<section>
    <paper-button raised class="blue" disabled?="{{ (! Validated) || (Submitted) }}" on-tap="{{ Submit }}">
    <core-icon icon="send"></core-icon> 
             Process
    </paper-button>
</section>

<paper-toast id="toast" text=""></paper-toast>

<core-ajax id="ajax" url="/import-pdi" method="POST" handleAs="json" response="{{ response }}" on-core-complete="{{ SubmitFinished }}"></core-ajax>
</template>

    <script>
        Polymer("import-pdi-form", {

            Validated: false,
            Submitted: false,

            FileInputLabel: "SELECT",
            ready: function () {
                this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#file").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
                    var container = document.querySelector("import-pdi-form");
                    container.Validated = (event.detail.valid.length != 0);
                    if (event.detail.valid.length == 0) {
                        container.shadowRoot.querySelector("#toast").text = "Invalid Format";
                        container.shadowRoot.querySelector("#toast").show();
                        container.FileInputLabel = "SELECCIONA L'ARXIU";
                    }
                    else {
                        container.FileInputLabel = event.detail.valid[0].name;
                        var form_data = new FormData();
                        form_data.append("file", event.detail.valid[0], event.detail.valid[0].name);
                        container.shadowRoot.querySelector("#ajax").body = form_data;
                        container.shadowRoot.querySelector("#ajax").contentType = null;
                    }
                });
            },
            Submit: function() {
                if ((this.Validated) && (! this.Submitted)) {
                    this.Submitted = true;
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#ajax").go();
                }
            },
            SubmitFinished: function(event, detail, sender) {
                if (detail.xhr.status == 200) {
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#toast").text = JSON.parse(detail.xhr.response).message;
                }
                else {
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#toast").text = "Server Error";
                }
                this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#toast").show();
                this.FileInputLabel = "SELECCIONA L'ARXIU";
                this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#file").reset();
                this.Submitted = false;
            }
        });
     </script>
```

Comment: I noticed in a lot of places you're using this.shadowRoot.querySelector to get at things with ids. You can use automatic node finding to do that much more efficiently
https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding

Comment: @robdodson: Thank you for your advise. I've just changed shadowRoot and all are running good. Besides that, I'm looking for the best way to pass form data to server. Right now I am using core-ajax but it seems a little heavy solution. Is there any standard about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For submitting a form that contains custom elements we currently recommend that you use the [`ajax-form` element](https://github.com/rnicholus/ajax-form). It looks like you may already be using the `file-input` element by the same author, so the two should work well together.

Comment: @AlbertHornos If i'm right, latest updates to core-input and paper-input makes submitting form without using ajax-form but still retaining the style of material design and posting via conventional means possible, if I understand properly. See the change log: https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2014/11/12/release-0.5.1/#0-5-1_coreinput

Comment: @Rexford That does not appear to be correct.  "The <paper-input> element doesn’t submit within the <form> element - the best practice is to use <paper-input> with a more modern XHR approach to submitting data, such as with the <ajax-form> element".  That statement also applies to other custom element form fields.

Comment: @RayNicholus Yeah youre right. The paper-input doesnt work unless ajax-form is used. But if one wants the paper-input design for thr ordinary input, then the input tag could be wrapped in the paper-input-decorator which will work when form is submitted normally